# Termination of a server program by a button in Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I am writing a server application in Java where i have in an activation method of `MyServer` class:

```
    System.out.println("The Base Station was activated");
    Socket s;       //Here it listens for new connections

    this.server = new ServerSocket(this.getPort());

    while(activated == true)
    {       
        s = this.server.accept();   
        ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(s);
        Thread servingThread = new Thread(ch);
        servingThread.start();    
    }
```

It is waiting for clients to connect and it spawns a thread to accommodate each client. I also want to support a deactivation button in my GUI, but i can't see how the ActionListener for that button, which is defined in a `MyServerFrame` class, can ever be called and change the status of `activated` variable if the above server code is stuck waiting in `accept`. How can i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to give access to the server socket inside the class holding the stop button handler (for example by passing the MyServer instance to the MyServerFrame instance) and inside the handler close the socket, such that the call to accept returns and then you can exit the while loop.

So inside the handler you should be able to do:

```
myServer.setActivated(false);
myServer.closeSocket(); // inside you have this.server.close();
// assuming you have passed the MyServer object to the form.
```

Comment: i did that but my problem seems to be that i can't click on "Deactivate" button of the Frame, so i never reach the handler code. The button is 'dead' and the program is stuck on the above while loop

Comment: Are you running the code with the while loop on a different thread or the same thread as main form?

Comment: the main form creates a Frame instance, and on the frame constructor i have the ActionListener that calls the method of the while loop. On the same Frame constructor i have the ActionListener that must end the server program. So it is the same thread i guess.

Comment: You will need to create another thread to run the code with the while loop. The main thread of the form needs to listen to messages from the user like your button click, but if you block it with the while loop, it cannot intercept your button click.

Comment: ok i got it thank you! (if i create a seperate thread to listen for connections, it will be able to spawn new threads to accommodate each client, right?!. Sorry for the dumb questions but i am new at Java!)